# Как удалить объект Audio из памяти

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть объект VueAudio

```
function VueAudio (src, options) {
    // Это псевдокод, он не полный
    this.tmp = {src: src, oprions: options}
    // Проверка ошибок и создание плеера
    this.init(src, options)
}
VueAudio.prototype.init = function(src, options) {
    this.$Audio = new Audio(src);
    // Создание объекта аудио
    // ...
}
```

Проблема в том что теперь если очистить $Audio или удалить

```
this.$Audio = {}
```

Сам объект Плеера останется и будет играть музыка в фоне.

Если создать новый объект, или заменить, звук наложится и в фоне уже будет 2 песни.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте предварительно останавливать звук:

```
this.$Audio.pause()
this.$Audio.currentTime = 0
```